# Not getting my row values to show in my Listview from my SQLite DB?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I've been working on creating a listview with rows and these row values display information stored in my database. My question is how do I fix the error I'm getting "column _id does not exist"? I've looked online and I found you're suppose to define the the column '_id' using as, but when I did it just failed. Maybe I'm missing something but after trying several different approaches I still get that error. Any ideas?

Here is the method that defines my query:

```
    String sql = "create table " + TABLE + "(" + C_ID + " int primary key, " +
    C_WORKOUT_NAME + " text, " + C_CLASSNAME + " text, " + C_CREATED_AT + " text)";

    db.execSQL(sql);
```

Here is the code that passes the database values into my rows:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    cursor = db.query(DBHelper1.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, 
    DBHelper1.C_CREATED_AT + " DESC");
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, FROM, TO);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I also have

```
    static final string C_ID= "_id"
```

08-10 19:47:52.176: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Starting: Intent {cmp=edu.njit.hss/.History } from pid 440
08-10 19:47:52.596: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(440): Shutting down VM
08-10 19:47:52.596: WARN/dalvikvm(440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-10 19:47:52.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 19:47:52.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {edu.njit.hss/edu.njit.hss.History}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
08-10 19:47:52.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
08-10 19:47:52.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-10 19:47:52.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1643)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I need a bit more information to help you. 
When it is exactly giving this error? 
How can it say that a column doesn't exist when there is no request for that column in the code you show? (I guess it is any other part of it)

As a starting point I'd suggest you to take a look to the DB:

- If you don't have a rooted device, execute your app in the emulator
- Pull the file from DDMS - go to the file tree and navigate to /data/data/your.app.package/databases/yourDatabaseName
- Open it with a sqlite browser (Lita, SQLiteDBBrowser), see how it looks and update the info here if you still need it

...we'll be waiting here :)

Comment: Okay I will do and post back tomorrow =)